# tkinter dynamic OptionMenu command not working

Tags: python, tkinter, optionmenu

I'm using python 2.7.9 and my current issue is that for some reason, my `OptionMenu`'s command isn't working. Below is sample code of what I mean.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
var = StringVar()
var.set("Choose a name...")
names = []

# Appends names to names list and updates OptionMenu
def createName(n):
    names.append(n)
    personName.delete(0, "end")
    menu = nameMenu['menu']
    menu.delete(0, "end")
    for name in names:
        menu.add_command(label=name, command=lambda name=name: var.set(name))

# what to run when a name is selected
def selection():
    print "Running"  # For testing purposes to see when/if selection runs
    print var.get()

# Option Menu for names
nameMenu = OptionMenu(root, var, (), command=lambda: selection())
nameMenu.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
nameMenu.config(width=20)

# Entry for user to submit name
Label(root, text="Name").grid(row=1, column=0)
personName = Entry(root, width=17)
personName.grid(row=1, column=1)

# Add person Button
Button(root, text="Add Person", width=20, command=
       lambda: createName(personName.get())).grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2)

mainloop()
```

The purpose of this theoretical program is just to add a name to the `OptionMenu`, and then when you select the name, it will print it. I can add names to the `OptionMenu` just fine, but when it comes time for the `OptionMenu` to run the `selection()` function, it won't.

Now my best guess as to what's wrong is simply that the `createName()` function that the button is calling is also using the `OptionMenu`'s command up due to the line

```
menu.add_command(label=name, command=lambda name=name: var.set(name))
```

Is there anyway around this? Is it possible for an `OptionMenu` to have multiple commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track... But instead of changing the StringVar you can pass the name into your `selection()` function like this:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

var = StringVar()
var.set("Choose a name...")
names = []

# Appends names to names list and updates OptionMenu
def createName(n):
    names.append(n)
    personName.delete(0, "end")
    menu = nameMenu['menu']
    menu.delete(0, "end")
    for name in names:
        menu.add_command(label=name, command=lambda name=name: selection(name))

# what to run when a name is selected
def selection(name):
    var.set(name)
    print "Running"  # For testing purposes to see when/if selection runs
    print name

# Option Menu for names
nameMenu = OptionMenu(root, var, ())
nameMenu.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
nameMenu.config(width=20)

# Entry for user to submit name
Label(root, text="Name").grid(row=1, column=0)
personName = Entry(root, width=17)
personName.grid(row=1, column=1)


# Add person Button
Button(root, text="Add Person", width= 20, command=lambda: createName(personName.get())).grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2)


mainloop()
```

Comment: command=lambda name=name: selection(name) seems to work but is quite confusing.

Comment: @EricLevieil What is confusing about that?  That's pretty standard stuff when it comes to calling functions with arguments from Tkinter widgets.

Comment: It works! Thank you! However I'm a little confused as to how it works since in `nameMenu = OptionMenu(root, var, (), command=lambda: selection())` , selection() isn't given a variable. How does the selection(name) function work if a variable isn't given? Is that just automatically given by whatever is selected in the OptionMenu?

Comment: @Matt_Jacket You can change that line to `nameMenu = OptionMenu(root, var, ())`  That `command` is going in as what is called when you select the empty drop down before you add a name... which wouldn't really make sense.

Comment: @Jkdc yes that is true, but the only issue with that is when I run the code, add a few random names, and go to select a name, the OptionMenu text won't change when I make a selection.

Comment: @Matt_Jacket Add `var.set(name)` to your `selection()` function.